# jquery mobile form submit button won´t work if i change the type

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I try to convert a website into a mobile site with help of jquerymobile.

There are issues with a "scroll" button with type="image", that won´t work if I convert into a mobile-button with type="submit" / or type"button"

( I want just a button that does the same thing, that the type"image"-button does before...)
Just a button, without the image...

I tried hours before I posted this here, so maybe you are able to help :)

my code snip so far...
original code:

```
    form name="example_form" method="post" action="example.php" target="_self">
                    <td  align="right">
                        <input type="hidden" name="select" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="example" value="<?php  echo $example; ?>" />
                        <input id="inputimg1" type="image" value="back"  width="89px" height="31px" onclick="this.form.select.value=this.value"/>

                    </td>

                    <td  align="left">
                        <input id="inputimg1" type="image" value="for" width="89px" height="31px" onclick="this.form.select.value=this.value"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="start" value="<?php  echo $example; ?>" />
                    </td>
                </form>
```

my "form" (the first ui-block-a is not working, the block-b is (because its type="image")

```
    <form method="post" action="example.php" target="_self" >
                    <div class ="ui-grid-a">


                    <div class="ui-block-a">

                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c" style="height:55px" align="center" >
                        <input type="submit" id="t" value="back" onclick="this.form.select.value=this.value"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="select" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="example" value="<?php  echo $example; ?>" />


                        </div> 
                    </div>


                    <div class="ui-block-b">

                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c" style="height:55px" align="center" >

                        <input type="image" value="for" onclick="this.form.select.value=this.value"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="start" value="<?php  echo $example2; ?>" />

                </div>  </div>  </div>
        </form>
```

the values "for" and "back" are alright. They are working on the type"image"-buttons.
But whyyy does it not do anything, if i simply change the type "image" into "submit"/"button"??

Thank you in advance,
best regards

Answer (score 0):

I took a moment to execute the code in ui-block-a and found that it does in fact set the hidden input named "select" to the value of that submit button ("back"). I don't understand what problem you are seeing, but the code is completely functional.

Regarding style approach, you would be better off separating your JavaScript and HTML and using event listeners to trigger functions. Your code would be easier to debug and maintain. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener